# Changing motherboard and CPU without having to reinstall everything on the OS hard drive

Tags: windows, cpu, motherboard

My current configuration (with last update of windows 10 pro) is the left one in the following table, and I intend to upgrade it to the right one, by changing only the motherboard and the CPU :

[image]

Everything is compatible, my only concerns being :

- I just perhaps (really not sure as the motherboard is quite recent and supports 9th gen intel CPUs) have to update the bios of the new motherboard with the old CPU so the motherboard could support the new CPU - which frightens me, but eh
- I would like not to have to reinstall everything (windows 10 included) as everything is already installed on the Samsung EVO SSD.

I came accross this microsoft post :

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-to-upgrade-motherboard-and-cpu-without/1550fa84-f7b1-4d39-86c8-327bca78d087

explaining that it is indeed possible, under certain conditions that are fulfilled in my case, not to have to reinstall windows 10 nor anything else except security software + GPU drivers.

I would like to have an advice regarding this. Is it really possible ? Is it really advised to proceed like this ? Isn't it perhaps clean to have a fresh start ? What is the best practice ?

Comment: Yes you can, but you will need to buy a new windows 10 license when done>>>>https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/motherboard-upgrade-with-windows-10/a41d5ab4-3bf7-4b07-8b07-7a1c5627b3c9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is technically possible, but doesnt always work.  As the article states, uninstall antivirus and your display drivers.  I would, if Windows doesnt already have the drivers, install the drivers for the disk controller.  Assuming there is no other hardware preventing Windows from booting, it should work.

That being said, I always prefer a clean install and update Windows.  This allows me to have a baseline install, then take an image of the machine absolutely clean of extra software.  Then, I install the absolute must have software I have on every machine and take another image.  This way I can always go back to either working image.  Just my preference.

Comment: I think I will go down the clean road. So, after I save somewhere safe all the stuff I have on my OS SSD (as well as on the other SSD), what do you recommand to do ? Leave the OS SSD as it is and choose, at the new win10pro install, to format it ? Other point : untying win10pro off of the motherboard and tying it to my MS Account to be able to activate it with new MB and CPU is alright, but is it possible then to untie win10pro from my MS account and tie it to the new MB ?

Comment: Yes it's possible to transfer your license to the new hardware, but you mant need to convince Microsoft to help with that, whether or not you can do that depends partly on which parts of the windows license/EULA are legal where you are.